# Rubocop:method has too many lines

Tags: ruby, enumerable, rubocop

Hello I am new at ruby programming.
Ran rubocop inspection in my project and it says:

> Method has too many lines. [13/10]   def refresh_status

Here is my methods:

```
def refresh_status
    lost = false
    in_progress = false
    won = false
    @bets.each do |bet|
      lost = true if bet.result == :lost
      if bet.result == :canceled
        @to_return /= bet.odd
        won = true
      end
      in_progress = true if bet.result == :in_progress
      won = true if bet.result == :won
    end
    def_result_after_refresh(lost, in_progress, won)
  end

  def def_result_after_refresh(lost, in_progress, won)
    if lost
      @result = :lost
    elsif in_progress
      @result = :in_progress
    elsif won
      @result = :won
    end
  end
```

Can't find a way to make that method shorter, maybe you could help?

Comment: All your conditionals comparing `bet.result`. You could use a `case` statement to make your code more expressive but maybe not shorter. Therefore you could do the initialization in one line,  `lost, in_progress, won = false, false, false` for example.

Comment: rubocop doesn't allow to use parallel (one line) assingments @sschmeck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) methods.

```
def refresh_status
  @to_return /= @bets.select { |bet| bet.result == :canceled }.map(&:odd).reduce(1, :*)

  results = @bets.map { |bet| bet.result == :cancelled ? :won : bet.result }.uniq
  @result = case
            when results.include?(:lost) then :lost
            when results.include?(:in_progress ) then :in_progress 
            when results.include?(:won) then :won
            end
end
```

Comment: so as I said I am a newbie so could you tell what map(&:odd) does? I know that it puts selected elements to list but what is `&:odd` ? @sschmeck

Comment: Good question. `bets.map(&:odd)` builds a new array from the bets array where all bets are replaced (or mapped) by it's value of bet.odd. It's a shortcut for `bets.map { |bet| bet.odd }`. Does it help? `reduce` is quite similar.

Comment: yes. For full rubocop acceptance I needed to make lines shorter and `when results.include?(:won ) then :lost` is not quite right it should be `when results.include?(:won ) then :won` by the way I will accept your answer